# digital artifacts on website, using android stock browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, android-layout

Dont know how to debug this (example attached), no errors returned in js console, i assume this might be caused by some certain css property (or maybe curtain.js), could someone point me in right direction? Already prepared code targetting this browser and im ready to show some basic contact info/logo for its users, though maybe theres some workaround?

Works fine in every desktop browser/mobile ie/mobile chrome/safari. Im unable to reproduce this bug on android 2.x (it has some other issues tho ^^). Happens on android 4.0.4. (at least on sgt 10.1)

Looks like this:

[image: android stock browser rendering artifacts]

Should look like this: 
[image]

some js libs i used:

```
<script src="site_media/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/media.match.min.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="site_media/js/curtain.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/js/scripts.js"></script>
```